# Can a non-conservative force be an internal force of a system?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, conservative-field

Are all internal forces conservative? Is it possible for a non-conservative force to be an internal forces? If yes, please give a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

Take *any* non-conservative force. Now define your new system to be all the things which interact with this force. This force is now "internal" and still non-conservative.

Answer (score 1):

The friction between two solid bodies that are in contact and sliding is a nonconservative internal force.

Answer (score 0):

Any force, whether conservative or non-conservative, can act as internal force depending on the definition of system.

For example, imagine two blocks A and B on a smooth horizontal surface with B lying on top of A. Assume the upper surface of A to be rough. Now, let's apply a force $F$ on block A in the horizontal direction. Depending on the magnitude of $F$, the mass of B and the coefficient of static friction on the surface of A, block B will either move along sticking to the surface of A or move horizontally in the direction of force with some acceleration. In both cases, there is frictional force acting on the interface of block B and A. On block B, it acts in the direction of force and on block A it acts in the opposite direction. If you define block A and B as your system, then the frictional forces act equal and opposite to each other. In this case, the frictional forces act as internal forces. But, if you take only block B as your system, there is only one frictional force acting on it and this force is an external force.

TL;DR: Whether a force is external or internal depends on the definition of the system.